# Upperbound for the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\ln^2\left(\frac{a_j}{b_j}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to estimate an upperbound for the series
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\ln^2\left(\frac{a_j}{b_j}\right)$$
where $a_j,b_j$ are real sequences, $\sum_ja_j$ and $\sum_jb_j$ converge.

Comment: If $a_n=\frac1{n^2}$ and $b_n=\frac1{n^3}$, then the sum is $\infty$.   If $a_n=\frac1{n^3}$ and $b_n=\frac1{n^2}$, then the sum is also $\infty$.  I'm not sure what kind of bound you expect.

Comment: Even tho i thought it was going to converge, i think i found two convergent series $a_j$ and $b_j$ for which $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\ln^2\left(\frac{a_j}{b_j}\right)=+\infty$

Comment: Exactly, i got $a_j=1/j^2$ and $b_j=1/j^4$, both convergent, but $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\ln^2\left(\frac{a_j}{b_j}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\ln^2\left(n^2\right)=+\infty$.

Comment: Okay, you answered my question. Thanks! I hadn't thought about this possibility.